# Elastic search through multiple fields of 1-N related data in one index

Tags: elasticsearch, relationship, parent-child

I've been stuck for a couple of days now with this issue, reading the Elastic docs back and forth to no avail. I hope someone could push me the right way.

Suppose there are two types of data - a parent and a child, that have 1-N relationship. I store them in the same index, using [custom `type` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html). They have some common and some different fields. To give a concrete example, the index and some input data might look something like:

```
PUT /myindex
{
  "mappings":
  {
    "properties": {
      "type": {"type": "keyword"},
      "fileid" : {"type": "keyword"},
      "dirid": {"type": "keyword"},
      "filename": {"type": "text"},
      "fileauthor": {"type": "text"},
      "dirpath": {"type": "text"}
    }
  }
}
PUT /myindex/_doc/1
{
  "type": "dir",
  "dirid": 1,
  "dirpath": "/home/jd/"
}
PUT /myindex/_doc/2
{
  "type": "dir",
  "dirid": 2,
  "dirpath": "/home/jd/Documents/CV/"
}
PUT /myindex/_doc/3
{
  "type": "file",
  "dirid": 2,
  "fileid": 1,
  "filename": "My-Resume.pdf",
  "fileauthor": "John Doe"
}
PUT /myindex/_doc/4
{
  "type": "file",
  "dirid": 1,
  "fileid": 2,
  "filename": "Some-CV.pdf",
  "fileauthor": "John Doe"
}
PUT /myindex/_doc/5
{
  "type": "file",
  "dirid": 1,
  "fileid": 3,
  "filename": "book.pdf",
  "fileauthor": "John Doe"
}
```

Now I want to search the text fields using rather complex (multi-word) queries, such as `John Doe CV`. For individual `type="dir"` or `type="file"` it is straightforward (and the query would return document with `_id=4`), but I would also like to get "mixed" results where part of the query is contained in the parent-specific fields and the rest in the child-specific fields. In my example data and query, I'd like it to return also `_id=3`, since the author is `John Doe` and parent `dirpath` contains the keyword `CV`.

I'm happy just to get the parent, it's enough for what I need. (I would indeed prefer just to get the parent, but that is something on top of the current problem I'm having.)

Somehow I haven't found a way to do it. I am aware of the `join` type, but that does not seem to help here, rather on the contrary. Many suggestions, SO questions and documentation items are outdated as the previously recommended practice become deprecated.

Sure, I could just populate each entry with all data (each `type="file"` would just copy the parent's `dirpath` values), but that is against all my perception of optimal use of memory and space.

Does anyone know where to look further, please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am sorry it is a little hard to follow what you are trying to do. What I would suggest is post a couple sample documents, and also post what is the output you are expecting those documents in the result after querying. This probably will help to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry for not being clear right away. Hopefully I've clarified it a bit more. Please note that the dir/file example is a lot simplified version of what I'm doing, but shall be representative.